# symfony 4 keep user authenticated with UsernamePasswordToken

Tags: symfony

I've created social connect between twitter and my app. I got the user's data and I'd like to authenticate then. Managed to create a firewall where the users are not forced to authenticate (not mandatory) **security.yaml**:

```
app_user_provider:
  entity:
    class: App\Entity\User
    property: combinedId
```

...

```
member:
  anonymous: ~
  pattern: ^/
  provider: app_user_provider
  logout:
    path: logout
    target: /
    invalidate_session: false
```

*combinedId* is an *User* class property which is unique.

So I created the entity of *User* class, and flushed successfully, and I try to set up and store the token in the controller:

```
  /**
   * @param TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage
   * @param EventDispatcherInterface $eventDispatcher
   * @param Request $request
   * @param User $user
   * @return bool
   */
  private function auth(TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage, EventDispatcherInterface $eventDispatcher, Request $request, User $user) {
    $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, self::FIREWALL, $user->getRoles());
    $tokenStorage->setToken($token);
    $event = new InteractiveLoginEvent($request, $token);
    $eventDispatcher->dispatch($event);

    return true;
  }
```

at **this point** everything is fine. If I terminate the code here and take a look on the profiler, it says *username* is fully authenticated in the *member* area ... *usernamePasswordToken*, */logout* ... present so we can say it's working here.

The problem is, when I reloading the page, or navigate to another page, the token lost/changed. I'm authenticated as *anon.* user again, with *anynymousToken* in the *member* area (also no /logout action under the user's tab in the profiler).

So the area didn't change but the token.
How can I store the token properly?

**UPDATE 1**:

After setting the token, I've tried to save it in the session:

```
$session = $request->getSession();
$session->set('_security_' . self::FIREWALL, serialize($token));
$session->save();
```

but this is not in the next request (gone / invalidated?).

Comment: Have you checked whether the token is stored in the session?

Comment: @NicoHaase i've tried, see "UPDATE 1" in my post. Unfortunately, doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

I found out that, you have to add **userName** to your *User* class serialize/unserialize methods because the symfony looking for that data.

So in the log messages > debug you'll see:

```
Cannot refresh token because user has changed.
[▼
  "username" => "someUserNameHere"
  "provider" => "Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Security\User\EntityUserProvider"
]
```

And the solution is (adding the **$this->userName** to the following part of the User.php):

```
  public function serialize() {
    return serialize([$this->id, $this->combinedId, $this->userName]);
  }



  public function unserialize($serialized) {
    [$this->id, $this->combinedId, $this->userName] = unserialize($serialized, ['allowed_classes' => false]);
  }
```